is there any way to replace kalman
Is there any more efficient and useful algorithm that can replace the extension Kalman（including all of kalman here),have any other way to do predictions and observations？
Kalman filters are always divergent and have some hysteresis, can there be a more accurate filter to solve this problem (need to be used on NUC

This may helps you: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/11633/alternatives-to-kalmam-filter

What problem are you trying to solve? That would inform algorithms that might be reasonable alternatives.
